# Can Salesforce CPQ UI be exposed via Lighting Out?

Tags: cpq, lighting-out

I have a customer who uses LifeRay as a portal and wants to leverage this to allow their partners to generate quote using Salesforce CPQ. I guess this can be done using CPQ APIs but I understand there are some rules and workflow embedded in CPQ UI. Hence the question is if I create a Lightning Component for CPQ UI, can I expose this using Lightning Out into LifeRay?